# How do I use "incremental reveal" with the new Google Drive Presentation creator?

Tags: google-slides

I am using Google Drive to create a presentation in which I have four square objects. I want one to be revealed each time I click (I think the old phrasing was: "incremental reveal").

Is there any way to do this other than creating four separate slides with each keyframe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to set them up as animations to show when you actually present the slides.

To set these up, create the four objects you'd like to reveal incrementally.

1. Right-click on the first object you want to reveal and select **Animate**
2. The animation right navigation menu will appear, allowing you to select how you want the object to appear (fade in, etc) as well as the timing of the reveal (slow, fast). You can also define what action will cause the object to animate (defaults to on-click)
3. Repeat process for the remaining 3 objects

You'll see the final product of all the animations in the right-menu. Once you create all the animations you want, you can reorder, change, or remove the existing animations, as well as add new ones.

Here's a screenshot (below) as well as a link to the [help article on creating animations](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1689475).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted. I will accept when the timer's done.